# Getting access to Button parent

Tags: c#

I'm using a Button in a class. When the button is pressed, it should call a routine with the button's corresponding text. How do I convert the sender into a String_Entry? Also, I'm quite a newbie regarding object oriented/class programming, so comments are welcome.

```
public class String_Entry
{
    public TextBox textbox;
    public Button send;
    // other stuff

    public String_Entry()
    {
        textbox = new TextBox();
        send = new Button();
        send.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bSend_Click);
        // put in GUI, set parameters and other stuff
    }

    // other stuff

    private void bSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Trying to get the corresponding String_Entry from the Button click event
        Button cntrl = (Button)sender;
        String_Entry entry = (String_Entry)(cntrl.Parent);

        parse.ProcessHexLine(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass `this`?

Comment: Look up the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Parent property.  You are not using it properly.  Also check out the Tag property.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution of encapsulating a button with a textbox and the event handler is sound. It just goes wrong in the event handler:

```
private void bSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button cntrl = (Button)sender;
    String_Entry entry = (String_Entry)(cntrl.Parent);

    parse.ProcessHexLine(entry);
}
```

Firstly, there is no point to doing anything with `sender` as it'll be the same as the field `send`. Next `cntrl.Parent` will give you a reference to the Form, or other container object, that contains the button, not this instance of `String_Entry`. To access that, use `this`. So you can change the event handler to:

```
private void bSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parse.ProcessHexLine(this);
}
```